# 2 and/or 4 belongs to f(x) image?

Tags: functions

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^ 2+x}+4$$

How can I now if 2 and or 4 belongs to the image of the function? (in a General Way so I can apply it to other functions)

Answer (score 0):

Well, try setting $f(x)$ equal to $2$, and seeing if the equation is consistent. Do the same for $f(x)=4$.

Answer (score 0):

To decide whether a number $a$ is in the image of that $f$, set $f(x)=a$ and solve for $x$. You'll get a quadratic equation (with the restriction $x^2+x\ne0$). If it as real solutions, then $a$ is in the image. Otherwise, no.

However, since  $x^2+x\ne0$, we must have $x\ne0$ and so $f(x)$ simplifies to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}+4$, which makes $f(x)=a$ much easier to solve.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't know how to go on after passing the 4 to the other side and add it to 2. $$2 = \frac{x}{x^2+x}+4$$
$$-2 = \frac{x}{x^2+x}$$